# Get the last tr which id begins with Row_

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get with jQuery the greater id for all `tr` in a table.

If I have this table:

```
<table id="productsTable" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr id="Row_0">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Row_1">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Row_2">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Row_3">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I want to get the id `Row_3`.

I can use the `:last selector`, `$( "tr:last" )` but it doesn't work because it returns the row for the `<tfoot>` section.

Maybe there is a way to add a filter to the `:last selector` to find the last `tr` with an id that begins with `Row_`.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[attribute start with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**:

```
$("tr[id^='Row_']:last" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the rows in tbody have the id just use `tbody` in selector

```
$( "tbody tr:last" )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```js
alert($("tr[id^='Row_']:last").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="productsTable" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr id="Row_0">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Row_1">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Row_2">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Row_3">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

If you just want last tr inside `tbody` then use:

```
$("tbody tr:last")
```